# Access Point NetgearWG602 - set home page

Tags: wireless-access-point

I want that everytime someone connect to my wifi network, the first browser webpage is one that I can set via admin page.

How can I achieve this with AP NetgearWG602?

I dont have any experience about that.

Just want to know whether it is possible and if so some hint to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Search for "Captive Portal"

Comment: thanks @CharlieRB, but this doesn't seem to be a duplicated of your link. I am asking whether it is possible with a specific AP

Comment: Im pretty sure this is a duplicate im pretty sure i read the exact same thing or pretty close a day and a half ago.

Comment: can u pretty point me to that :)